# Referring to a mathematical element: to drop or not to drop the "the"

Tags: article-writing

As a non-native English speaker, this question about style comes back to me every time I'm writing a formal text.

Given a certain mathematical element, such as a matrix detoned by *M*. Which is the more correct way to refer to it:

*"Note that matrix M is symmetric"* or *"Note that **the** matrix M is symmetric"* ?

Comment: Including the "the" strikes me as more correct.

Comment: I think it makes sense either way.

Comment: In this case use the "the" but there are other examples where such articles can be dropped

Comment: "Note that the matrix $M$ is symmetric", but on the other hand "Note that $M$ is symmetric". That is what sounds correct to me.

Comment: Im a native speaker and most people generally praise my writing skills.  I for one, in mathematics, dont really see a difference and couldnt care less, really.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware that "Note (that) M is symmetric" is enough, but my question focuses on the use (or not) of the article "the".

Answer (score 0):

For clarity and correctness, most English speakers would prefer "Note that the matrix $M$ is symmetric" or "Note the matrix $M$ is symmetric" to "Note matrix $M$ is symmetric". This assumes you haven't introduced $M$ yet; if you have, "Note $M$ is symmetric" is fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It made me wonder if I should have been more explicit in the question, but you got my point correctly. In this case, I was referring to an element already defined and I wanted to recall its nature (e.g., matrix).